# How to create a new array from this existing array by matching the similar id from an dynamic array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I need to create a new array by filtering the data.

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "manager",
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "cashier",
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "customer",
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "cashier_2",
      "test_id": "500"
    }
  ],
}
```

I need to filter this array and create a new array by using the `test_id` this is the expected format.

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": [manager, cashier, customer],
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "cashier_2",
      "test_id": "500"
    }
  ],
}
```

I tried using the filter method and using the map method but couldn't get the expected output.

```
  let x = [];

   const test = userRoles?.map((item, index, element) => {
     let next = element[index+1];
        if(item?.test_id == next?.test_id){
            x.push(item?.role)   
         }
     })
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `map()` works here, as it just maps entries to (new) entries, but you need to group them. This is a job for `reduce()`, which lets you create anything out of the entries.

In this case, an object for easy lookup between `test_id` and grouped entries works well:

```js
const data = {
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "manager",
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "cashier",
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "customer",
      "test_id": "123"
    },
    {
      "role": "cashier_2",
      "test_id": "500"
    }
  ],
}

const res = Object.values(data.roles.reduce((groups, entry) => {
    groups[entry.test_id] ??= {test_id: entry.test_id, role: []}
    groups[entry.test_id].role.push(entry.role)
    return groups
  },{})
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is working fine. can you give me a bit of demonstration about how dose object.values and reduce function works in javascript?

Comment: Oh, `reduce()` works the same as `map()` in that the inner function gets called once for each element in the list, but each iteration also gets the returned value from the previous call. You can set the initial input to the first iteration as second argument to `reduce()`. And the return from the last iteration is the output of `reduce()`. You can find lots of examples on the web, I'd recommend to have a look at them to see how it works. The `Object.entries()` just returns all values of an object as an array, i.e. `Object.entries({a:1, b:2})` will give you `[1,2]`.

Answer (score 2):

To create the desired new array from the existing array, you can use the `reduce()` method to iterate through the roles and group them by their `test_id`. For each role, you can check if there is already an object in the accumulator array with the same `test_id`. If there is, you can push the role to the existing object's `role` array. If there isn't, you can create a new object with the `test_id` and an array containing the role, and push it to the accumulator array. Here's some code that should do the trick:

```JavaScript
const roles = [
  {
    "role": "manager",
    "test_id": "123"
  },
  {
    "role": "cashier",
    "test_id": "123"
  },
  {
    "role": "customer",
    "test_id": "123"
  },
  {
    "role": "cashier_2",
    "test_id": "500"
  }
];

const groupedRoles = roles.reduce((accumulator, role) => {
  const existingGroup = accumulator.find(group => group.test_id === role.test_id);
  
  if (existingGroup) {
    existingGroup.role.push(role.role);
  } else {
    accumulator.push({
      test_id: role.test_id,
      role: [role.role]
    });
  }
  
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(groupedRoles);
```

This should output:

```JavaScript
[  {    "test_id": "123",    "role": ["manager", "cashier", "customer"]
  },
  {
    "test_id": "500",
    "role": ["cashier_2"]
  }
]
```

Note that the code assumes that the `roles` array is already sorted by `test_id`. If that's not the case, you can use the `sort()` method to sort it first. Also, I've used `console.log()` to show the result, but you can return the `groupedRoles` array from a function or use it in some other way as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries()` in combination with `Array#reduce()` and `Array#map()` methods as follows:

```js
const 
      input = { "roles": [ { "role": "manager", "test_id": "123" }, { "role": "cashier", "test_id": "123" }, { "role": "customer", "test_id": "123" }, { "role": "cashier_2", "test_id": "500" } ] },
      
      output = {
        roles: Object.entries(
          input.roles.reduce(
            (acc,cur,index) => ({
                ...acc,[cur.test_id]:acc[cur.test_id] ?
                [...[acc[cur.test_id]].flat(),cur.role] : cur.role
            }), {}
          )
        )
        .map(
          ([test_id, role]) =>
          ({role, test_id})
        )
      };

console.log( output );
```